# Deserialize JSON from String to object

Tags: ios, json, swift

I try to deseralize my JSON that look like this :

```json
{
  "access_token": "This_is_my_token"
  "item01": "blabla"
  "item02": "blabla"
  ...
}
```

and I want to save only `access_token` into a variable. Not a big deal.
For exemple, with PHP it is something really simple like:

```php
<?php

  $jsonObj = json_decode($jsonString);
  $access_token = $jsonObj["access_token"];

?>
```

But it doesn't look this easy with Swift. I try many things but nothing works for me.

Here is the code I have:

```swift
dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
            do {
                let anyObj: AnyObject? = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataString, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions([])) as AnyObject
                guard let access_token = anyObj?.firstItem as? [String: AnyObject]
                    else {return}
                print(access_token)

            } catch {
                print("JSON Deserial. Error")
            }
```

with this code, I can't manipulate `anyObj` like I do with `$jsonObj` in PHP, there is no way to do something like `anyObj["access_token"]`

How can I access to this item in the object ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply call this function by passing your data here and it will return a dictionary. From that dictionary you can pick access_token value.

```
class func parseJsonToDictionary(data: Data) -> ([String:AnyObject]?,Error?) {

        let _ =  NSString(data: data, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

        do {
            let JSONObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
            return (JSONObject as? [String:AnyObject],nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            return (nil,error)
        }

    }
```

Comment: I seems very good but when I `print(json.0["access_token"])` the ouput is `Optional(my_super_access_token)` instead of only `my_super_access_token`, do you know why ?

Comment: Simply use if let and force unwrap it.Then it will remove the optional.

Answer (score 2):

If you are having json string and not json data then you can use this method to convert it to dictionary.

```
func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [String: Any]? {
    if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
        do {
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return nil
}

let str = "{\"name\":\"James\"}"

let dict = convertToDictionary(text: str)
```

Later you can get value of access_token from dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of casting `anyObj to AnyObject` try casting it to a dictionary of strings like

```
let anyObj: AnyObject? = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataString, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions([])) as [String:String]
```

Then you can get accessToken by using `anyObj["access_token"]`

Comment: It doesn't work because `.jsonObject` produces `Any`, so it won't compile